# Лексические ошибки

Tags: лексика

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста правильно ли я исправил лексические ошибки.
1. Иные возможные противопоказания должен предусмотреть врач, ставящий процедуру. (Врач, ставящий процедуру, должен предусмотреть возможные противопоказания.) 
2. На протяжении тридцати лет Афанасьев выполнял роль кладовщика и экспедитора. (На протяжении тридцати лет Афанасьев выполнял обязанности кладовщика и экспедитора.)
3. Я дал сообщение в газету о свободных вакансиях. (Я подал объявление  в газету о свободных вакансиях.)
4. Подростки и тинейджеры – это главные посетители чатовых сайтов. (Подростки и тинейджеры – это основные посетители чатовых сайтов.) 
5. Войска получили значительный урон. (Войска понесли значительные потери.)
 6. Стихи молодого поэта скоро будут выпущены в журнале. (Стихи молодого поэта скоро будут опубликованы в журнале.)
 7. Кромешная разруха в Приморье, мощные снежные циклоны, небывалые морозы, разрушения газопроводов были отмечены прошлой зимой.  (Мощные снежные циклоны, небывалые морозы, приведшие к разрушению газопроводов, были отмечены минувшей зимой в Приморье.) 
  8. Автор статьи пишет ещё об одном требовании Л.Н. Толстого к языку, о требовании простоты и ясности, понятливости.

Answer (score 3):

1. Процедуру не ставят, а назначают 2.Можно. 3. Вакансия - это и есть свободное место. Поэтому либо вакансии либо свободные места. 4.Подростки и тинейджеры - это одно и тоже. 5, 6Можно. 7.Кромешная обычно бывает тьма. 8. Понятливость надо заменить.